# Python selenium getting text from text area

Tags: selenium, python-3.8

I am trying to copy the text area **message** into a variable so that I can parse it.

The text area has **message** as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Body><SubmitResponse xmlns="http://eftr</Error></SubmitResponse></Body></Envelope>
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<textarea class="v-textarea v-widget v-readonly v-has-width v-has-height v-textarea-readonly" rows="5" tabindex="-1" readonly="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></textarea>
```

I am trying the following and other configurations but I have not success:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
full_xpath = r'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/textarea'
path_to_chromedriver = r'C:\chromedriver'  # change path as needed
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)
.........
.........
content = browser.find_element_by_xpath(full_xpath).text
```

I am not sure how to achieve the above.

Basically `print(content)` should produce the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><Body><SubmitResponse xmlns="http://eftr</Error></SubmitResponse></Body></Envelope>
```

Comment: Are you positive the xpath is correct? It looks pretty brittle.

Comment: what does brittle mean? I am right clicking and copying full xpath.

Comment: @Zanam : what error are you getting?

Comment: @Zanam Brittle means it breaks easily. You copied full xpath but next time you run the test xpath might be slightly different so selenium will not be able to find the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

textcontent=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//textarea[@class='v-textarea v-widget v-readonly v-has-width v-has-height v-textarea-readonly']"))).get_attribute("value")
```

in textarea text is stored as value,

an example text area:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The textarea element</h1>

<form action="/action_page.php">
<label for="w3review">Review of W3Schools:</label>
<textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" rows="4" cols="50">
  At w3schools.com you will learn how to make a website. They offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.
  </textarea>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Click the "Submit" button and the form-data will be sent to a page on the 
server called "action_page.php".</p>
</body>
</html>
```

you can use above example html and in console try

```
   $('textarea').value
```

Answer (score 0):

use following `xpath` to idetify the element.

```
content = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@class='v-textarea v-widget v-readonly v-has-width v-has-height v-textarea-readonly']").text
```

---

Or use `get_attribute("innerHTML")`

```
content = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@class='v-textarea v-widget v-readonly v-has-width v-has-height v-textarea-readonly']").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

---

I would suggest use `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `visibility_of_element_located()`

```
content=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//textarea[@class='v-textarea v-widget v-readonly v-has-width v-has-height v-textarea-readonly']"))).text
```

you need to import below libraries

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```